# Why is .NET telling me my function is ambiguous?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am working on a website in .NET 4, and it is giving me the following error:

`'Trim' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'MyLib.WEB.TextboxEx, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings'.`

Problem is, which is confusing me, is that these functions have completely different signatures, so I have no idea why they would conflict.

The System function is defined as:

```
Public Function Trim(str As String) As String
```

While the MyLib one is defined as:

```
<Extension> Public Function Trim(
target As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
) As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

Given that they have wholly different signatures apart from the name, how can they possibly be ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because overloading only works within the same class, it cannot tell if you're passing the wrong parameters to the method you meant to call. Best to tweak the using statements or fully qualify your call.

Comment: Ah, yes... that's what it is. I was calling it as `myvar = Trim(dra.NullOf("ADDRESS", ""))`, where dra is a DataRow. NullOf, being a data-oriented method, just returns Object, and so the compiler cannot determine whether I'm passing it a string or a textbox. Got it... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Though I am confused, because this code was working fine the other day, doing - I guess - runtime validation... not sure why it suddenly stopped working. Odd. Oh well, ... better to make it explicit anyway and cast my dra values to string. *shrug*